# How to model motion of a ball being passed on between multiple characters

Tags: animation

i do not have a file to share for this question, but i will try my best to explain the issue. I want to create a football scene where multiple characters pass ball to each other. I have been using a Nurbs Path and follow Curve constraint on ball until now for ball motion. But the issue is that the speed of ball is dependent on the length of the Nurbs Path. THis is not helpful when there are many characters passing the ball around.

What are other ways i can control the ball movement so that its not restricted to the length of the Urbs path, instead i can move the ball at any speed and put it at any location on the scene at any point.

Comment: Using keyframe animation with interpolation set to Bézier. The closer the keyframes are together, the faster moves the ball. And with the Bézier interpolation you can tweak the curves to make a motion speed up or slow down.

Comment: You could use the Curve modifier on an object instead, parent the ball to this object, and move this object, it will only cause a problem if you extrude the start point